# Can't get the token of the Google account

Tags: google-signin

I follow the instruction to send the id token of the Google account to the back end server to be authenticated but it seems like the token does not exist.

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  console.log('Token: ' + id_token); 
}
```

The line `Token:` is not printed in the console. Anybody could tell me what's going on? Much appreciated

Comment: Is everything else working as expected? Can you get email, name etc?

Comment: Can you `console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse())` and tell me what you get?

Comment: Thanks @agektmr I have to rebuild the project like million times and finally it works